# How did Barney & Ted know that Robin was searching for that locket in Central Park?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

In Season 8 Episode 23/24, Robin looks for the locket in Central Park. She think to ask Barney & Ted to come to Central Park. But she doesn't tell anyone that she is Central Park. How can Ted & Barney reach that location.  I thought Robin didn't say that she was in Central Park

Comment: Maybe they just know like it's supposed to be romantic destiny / fate or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that this entire show is a flashback, representing the story that Ted is telling to his kids.  There are many things shown in the show that are factually incorrect, including but not limited to: people eating sandwiches when they were really smoking weed, everyone in the group being smokers even though it isn't ever mentioned except in one episode, and *Lily and Marshall literally communicating through telepathy* and, on at least one occasion, passing plot-relevant information to one another by doing so.

What we see on screen is what Ted tells his kids, not a full and proper accounting of what really happened.  The simplest explanation to your question is that Ted neglected to relate to his kids how he and Barney found out Robin was in Central Park.

Comment: I agree with you, but this is not an answer. Please add a comment if it is not a perfect relevant answer. Thanks

Comment: I disagre..this is a perfectly acceptable answer. If it is not, please explain **why** not.

Comment: This is the explanation of lot of things in that show. As narrator Ted is not very reliable.

Comment: @anvesh.veerelli: you cannot rely on the meticulous accuracy of a narrator who has already proven to be inaccurate.